# JGit - IllegalArgumentException during add command

Tags: java, git, jgit

When using JGit to add files to a repo, I'm getting an IllegalArgumentException  The message is "Invalid path: /the path here".

I'm using the documented approach of calling:

```
git.add().addFilePattern(".").call();
```

Anyone run into this before?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: After further inspection, the exception is being thrown inside of DirCacheEntry.  According to the source:  "@throws IllegalArgumentException If the path starts or ends with "/", or contains "//" either "\0". These sequences are not permitted in a git tree object or DirCache file."  That's all find and dandy, but my code works to add lots of other files.  I can't figure out why it doesn't work for this one...

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace? What version of JGit do you use? Does your repository have a file or folder named 'the path here'? If so, is it at the repository root or nested?

Comment: It's on a different system, so it's a little tricky for stack traces.  I'm working on debugging, and it may just be an issue with my code, not the API.  I'll keep you in the loop.

Comment: My current thought is that I don't have the appropriate dependencies, or the wrong versions of them.  I just snagged a couple of jars from Egit, so I'll grab the latest JGit from Maven w/correct dependencies and let ya know.

Comment: Also, for more info, apparently the JGit version is 1.3, which seems quite out of date.  Perhaps I'll just try the latest version...